# Sending parameter to Link to a Router component Reacts

Tags: reactjs

Im currently trying to send a state from the Link component to the Router component.

The router component looks like this:

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/banner/edit/:id'
>
  {!user && <Redirect to="/login" />}
  {user && org && <EditBanner uid={user.uid} org={org} />}
</Route>
```

This component is only rendered when the user is not null, and when the org is not null.

The EditBanner has a state called: bannerTitle:

```
export const EditBanner = ({ uid, org }) => {

  // States
  const [bannerTitle, setBannerTitle] = useState(null);
  ...
```

And when I am using Link to go to the component, I want to pass in the bannerTitle as a property to set the state in the EditBanner component. However, this is not having any effect on the Component.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/banner/edit/" + banner.id,
    state: { bannerTitle: "HELLO" }
  }}
>
  Edit
</Link>
```

Where can I get the passed props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [useLocation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook which provides a [location object](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location) which has `state`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

export const EditBanner = ({ uid, org }) => {
  let location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.state);
  }, [location])

  // ...
}
```

Hopefully that helps!